# BASH - Remove string from filename

Tags: bash

I'm trying to remove some strings from filenames i have in a directory using bash. I've tried the following with no success.

`rename --version`

`rename from util-linux 2.23.2`

`rename -v 's/[.].*//' *`

`rename -v 's/\.vesta-01:2,//' *`

Original File Name(s):

1667874526.M308257P1693.vesta-01:2,

1667883117.M371701P32232.vesta-01:2,

Desired File Name(s):

1667874526

1667883117

Answer (score 2):

`rename` from `util-linux` doesn't accept Perl substitution. See [man 1 rename](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html):

```
rename [options] expression replacement file...
```

You can use `mv` in a loop with parameter expansion instead:

```bash
for f in *.vesta-01:2, ; do
    mv "$f" "${f%%.*}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `mv` with bash parameter expansion instead:

```
$ ls 166*
1667874526.M308257P1693.vesta-01:2  1667883117.M371701P32232.vesta-01:2
$ f1="1667874526.M308257P1693.vesta-01:2" ; mv "$f1" "${f1%%.*}"
$ f2="1667883117.M371701P32232.vesta-01:2" ; mv "$f2" "${f2%%.*}"
$ ls 166*
1667874526 1667883117
```